# Проверка на вводимый тип данных Java

Tags: java, типы-данных

Писал программку для терминала, понадобилась проверка на вводимый тип `String`, например, если ввести число, то ему покажет сообщение, что необходимо ввести `String`. Не знаю как сделать, вот что я пока написал:

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;

class StartVer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.print("Available commands:\n 1. Read\n 2. Write");

        String getCommand;
        Scanner getCommand_Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Тут нужна проверка, чтобы пользователь мог вводить только String
    }
}
```

Хотел сделать проверку примерно так:

```
while (!getCommand_Sc.hasNextLine()) {
   System.out.println("Enter string");
   getCommand.next();
}
```

Но ничего не получилось, нужна помощь

Comment: А какой еще инпут вы можете получить из System.in?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в вопросе весь мой код(я не понял ваш вопрос)

Comment: Терминал не поддерживает двоичные данные.

Comment: вы не можете ничего получить из system in кроме строки, в чем вопрос не понятно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    class StartVer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("-------------------");
            System.out.print("Available commands:\n 1. Read\n 2. Write\n\n");

            String getCommand;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Первый вариант
    //while ( sc.hasNextLong() || sc.hasNextDouble() )

    //Вариант через регулярку
        while (sc.hasNext("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))
            {
                System.out.println("Please, enter only string:");
                sc.next();
            }
            getCommand = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(getCommand);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть методы - hasNextLine, hasNextInt, hasNextBollean , которые позволяют найти данные соответствующего типа в потоке данных.

Метод hasNextLine() возвращает значение true , если у сканнера есть следующая входная строка. А если вы имеете ввиду что тип который вы должны получить это строковый , то с помощью nextLine() вы можете получать построчно введенные данные. А если вам нужно проработать исключение - поставьте проверку на null , что бы не было ошибки при вводе пустой строки.

Comment: `hasNextLine()` возвращает `true`, если введена строка?

Comment: Если в потоке ввода находятся данные соответствующего типа, эти методы возвращают true.

Comment: я имею ввиду, вернет ли `hasNextLine()` `true`, если обнаружит в потоке данных тип `String` ?

Comment: Метод hasNextLine() возвращает значение true , если у сканнера есть следующая входная строка. А если вы имеете ввиду что тип который вы должны получить это строковый , то  с помощью nextLine() вы можете получать построчно введенные данные. А если вам нужно проработать исключение - поставьте проверку на null , что бы не было ошибки при вводе пустой строки.